# Using append() with a df.loc == statement Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, append

I'm looking to add a 2nd condition to the code below to append a string 'Other ' before the text. I've tried assigning it to a variable and calling it within the code to no success. The reason for this is when creating the report we can investigate all "Others" within the same visualisation whilst not being separate from the main job column

```
 import pandas as pd
 import os
 os.chdir('/Users/')
 df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

df()
Job?     Other
Hitman   NaN
King     NaN
Other    Farmer
# Replace all 'Others with values from the other subsequent other column' 
#Other columns dropped later on in code.
df.loc[df['Job?'] == 'Other', 'Are you?'] = df['If Other: Job?']
```

Would it be better to write a for statement prior to this to change and use the slice later on? if so would it be something like this?

```
for row in df.loc(["If Other"], axis=1):
df[row] = df[row].append("other ")
```

Editing for more clarity:

want I want is for the result farmer to appear as (or close to)

```
Job
Hitman
King
Other: Farmer
```

Further Edit for jezrael:

If i have multiple columns as follows

```
Job, Other_1, Position, Other_2, Education, Other_3,
A    NaN      A         NaN      A          Nan
Other Farmer  Other     CEO      Other      Github



 #a for loop like the following:
   for row in df.loc(["Other_1", "Other_2", "Other_3"], axis=1):
    df[row] = df[row].append("other ")
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need replace values by condition with joined columns:

```
df.loc[df['Job?'] == 'Other', 'Job?'] = df['Job?'] + ': ' + df['Other']
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Job?'] = np.where(df['Job?'] == 'Other', df['Job?'] + ': ' + df['Other'], df['Job?'])
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Job?'] = df['Job?'].mask(df['Job?'] == 'Other', df['Job?'] + ': ' + df['Other'])

df = df.drop('Other', axis=1)
print (df)
            Job?
0         Hitman
1           King
2  Other: Farmer
```

Also is possible add custom string, only remove `df['Job?']`:

```
df['Job?'] = df['Job?'].mask(df['Job?'] == 'Other', 'ooother: ' + df['Other'])
#last remove column if necessary
df = df.drop('Other', axis=1)
print (df)
              Job?
0           Hitman
1             King
2  ooother: Farmer
```

EDIT:

I think you can create `dictionary` of columns and in loop apply solution:

```
d = {'Job':'Other_1', 'Position':'Other_2', 'Education':'Other_3'}

for k,v in d.items():
    df[k] = df[k].mask(df[k] == 'Other', 'other: ' + df[v])

df = df.drop(list(d.values()), axis=1)
print (df)
             Job    Position      Education
0              A           A              A
1  other: Farmer  other: CEO  other: Github
```

Comment: you sir are my guru, could you explain what the .mask does in this instance? 

works perfectly! 

could you also explain if I could use a for loop with multiple column names?  (I assume this would make the code cleaner)?

Comment: @Datanovice - You are welcome! So mask get booelan mask `df['Job?'] == 'Other'` and for rows with `True` (if condition is `True`) apply `'ooother: ' + df['Other']`. for your second question, can you add some sample with multiple columns and expected output? thanks.

Comment: re-wrote my whole script and it works perfectly.

Much more elegant, you are the man! cheers.